# Which year for book reference: Copyright date or Library of Congress entry

Tags: citations

The verso of the title-leaf says "Copyright (C) 2004 by Ken Author". A few lines down comes the "Library of Congress Cataloging-in-Publication Data" which in the second but last line has an alphanumeric code followed by the number 2003. The last line ends with a ten-digit number that starts with "2003".

Which date to use in citation?

While opinion-based comments are appreciated, a convincing answer should come with reference to some standard guide on citation, please.

Answer (score 1):

The Library of Congress [Cataloging in Publication](https://www.loc.gov/publish/cip/) record (the CIP data) is a record prepared by the Library of Congress for a book *that has not yet been published*.  You should use the copyright date.